# Galleria jquery plugin - removing instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-instances, galleria, nyromodal

I have a page where i have several links that when clicked, load a gallery of images into Galleria within a Nyromodal lightbox.  When the lightbox is closed, i use $("#container").html('') to clear the contents of the lightbox including Galleria.

```
// open modal
$.nmManual("#container",{
    callbacks: {
        // loads Galleria after lightbox has finished opening
        afterReposition: function(nm) {
            $("#container #gallery").galleria({
                width:800,height:600
            });
        },
        // clear container with Galleria before closing the Modal
        beforeClose: function(nm) {
            $("#container").html('');
        }
    }
})
```

The next link i open properly opens a Nyromodal lightbox, properly populates Galleria with a new set of images, but using another instance of Galleria.  I would like to delete any old instances of Galleria.  How do i do this?  I don't see anything in the docs that allow me to remove instances manually.

I know that i have created multiple instances of Galleria by using Galleria.get().
This really doesn't have much to do with Nyromodal, but some context is always good :)

same issue here:
http://getsatisfaction.com/galleria/topics/allow_ability_to_remove_galleria_instances
(code does not work for current version)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply reuse existing instance of galleria, something like this

```
var gal;

if (!gal) {                 // not created yet
    $('#galleria2').galleria({
        dataSource: [],
        lightbox: true,
        some other options....
    });
    gal = $('#galleria2').data('galleria');
}
gal.load(images);
```

Comment: This works, unfortunately not the way i would like for my particular application.